# Appending MS ACCESS Table data to Excel Sheet?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to **Append a Microsoft ACCESS Table ** to a **Excel Sheet** but the data needs to be **appended** to the **Excel sheet**.  Meaning every time code is run in Access table data needs to be appended to Excel Sheet.

My current code is simply replacing the table in Excel (ACCESS- VBA Code used to export, DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport.....).

Is it possible to append the data to a table instead of replacing every time the code is run?

Comment: What is your current code? Also is it just new data that needs to be appended or the entire table?

Comment: Why don't you just link Excel to Access table and refresh when needed?

Comment: No, Not Excel --> Access. Its from Access table to Excel.